# Apparently no causes for the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined "

Tags: html, reactjs, typeerror

I have to show in the layout some data I take from a database. Here is the code I use to fetch the data:

```
    const [array, setArray] = useState([])
    const collectionRef = collection(db, "Collection")
    const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy("Order", "desc"))

    useEffect(() => {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
             onSnapshot(q, (data) =>
             setArray(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
         );
      }
    })
   }, [auth]);
```

Below is the html

```
    <div> 
        <h2>{array[0].Name}</h2>
    </div>
```

What baffles me most is that the error does not always show up, sometimes everything works and sometimes it stops working without apparent causes. If I do console.log of the array sometimes it prints the data and everything works, sometimes it prints an empty array and does nothing.
I state that that array is never modified, it is loaded at the beginning of the code and the data is only read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array` is empty for the first render and for all the other renders until the data is returned. Try something like:

```
<div> 
    <h2>{array.length && array[0].Name}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but why?

Comment: you are trying to access a property from `array[0]` which does not exist yet.  `array.length` is equivalent to `array.length !== 0` so `array[0].Name` will be evaluated after the array has something.